# Need help with mysql query

Tags: mysql

1. I am having a text-box which is auto complete.
2. When i enter the name on the text-box the auto complete will work and provide the list from table.
3. And when i click the save button the names which are entered in the text-box will inserted in a table. Until this, the process i working fine.
4. My case is : Already existing users should not show in auto-complete.

Table Structure :

1. Users Table

   uid, name
2. work table

   wid, from_uid, to_uid,

How the mysql query should be.. Any help regarding this will be thankful and gratedful...

Comment: what do you mean by "already inserted"? already inserted(written) in the text-box? for instance, you wrote "john, luis, jo" in the textbox. you mean that you don't want "john" to show as a suggestion, for the last "jo" because its already in the text-box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name
  from users
 where name like 'Jo%'
   and uid not in (select to_uid
                     from work
                    where from_uid = 666)
```

Supposing that user entered `Jo` substring and current user's id is `666`

or another query that does the same (not sure which one will be more efficient in your particular case) but uses `LEFT JOIN` instead of subquery:

```
   select name
     from users u
left join work w on w.from_uid = 666
                and u.uid = w.to_uid
    where name like 'Jo%'
      and w.to_uid is null
```